# Access vba opens a query and then report based on the query. They used to open in that order with the report in focus. Now the query has focus

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I use Access VBA to run a report and the customer asked for the ability to look at the query behind the report. The VBA looks like this:

```
Dim stDocName As String
stDocName = "FinInvProductionQuery"

DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, , acReadOnly
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewPreview
```

What used to happen is that the query would appear in the first tab after the report selection menu and the report would appear in the second tab, and the report would have the focus.

At some point in time - due to some kind of Office update "improvement" I would guess - they query opens in the first tab, the report opens in the second tab, and then focus returns to the query tab. It's driving my customer nuts. Granted, it doesn't take much to drive them nuts, but still I don't know why the change in behavior or how to correct it. I'm trying to find out how to set focus back to the report, but setfocus is for a control, not a report, at least as far as I can determine.

Has anyone else seen this change in behavior or have any idea how to get the focus back on the report?
Thanks in advance.

I tried to add the following code:

```
DoCmd.SelectObject acReport, stDocName, True
```

and I got the same behavior. I tried to set a sleep timer between the query and the report, but that didn't work either.

Comment: I also tried making a duplicate of the query with another name and using that for the report data source, thinking that maybe the report was causing the original query to be re-executed, but the behavior persists.

Comment: Might sound silly but try it in reverse and open the report first.

Answer (score 0):

I had a play with this and have come up with a solution that should work for you. Rather than trying to set focus on the report, set the focus to a *control* on the report using the timer. Set the `TimerInterval` to 30 either in the `OnOpen` event or on the report property itself. Then in the Report_Timer event, put in the following code substituting `YourControl` with the name of a control on your report:

```
Private Sub Report_Timer()
  TimerInterval = 0
  YourControl.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had tried to put a timer but it didn't help. However, the problem went away after another round of office updates.

Answer (score 0):

It's a timing issue. Try inserting a `DoEvents`:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, , acReadOnly
DoEvents
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewPreview
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had tried to put a DoEvents but it didn't help. However, the problem went away after another round of office updates.